# Select rows in a table (postgis) from selected features QGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis, qgis

How do I select rows in a table based on a key (PK) from another table. I have selected multiple polygons which is within a geografical region from one layer.

The attributes table from the selected layer look like this:

```
| Bloknr | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| 111-08 | xqyz     | xyzq     | qxyz     |
| 208-09 | abc      | cba      | bca      |
```

Where the row in question (row 1) is selected.

I now want to select this row from a nongeographic layer (from a postgresql database) with a table that looks like this:

```
| BLOKNR | Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
| 111-08 | cab       | bac       | cab       |
| 208-09 | abc       | cba       | bca       |
| 111-08 | cba       | bca       | cab       |
```

Where the first and third row is to be selected.

There is about 20.000.000 rows in the postgres table and multiple matches on each bloknr

I work in `qgis ver. 3.2` and `postgresql with PGadmin4`

Any help most appreciated.

UPDATE to answer the comments

It would be simple, if it was a matter of doing it within postgres - it's kind of made for that - but i cannot figure out how to query within qgis i would like not to have to export each table (I have a few, and for each i need multiple selection queries, based on geography) to postgresql - partly because i would like to keep the workflow in qgis, and partly because the export feature in the DB manager of qgis gives me this error - which i think means that i have to make all the tables manually.

> " ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown,
>   integer, unknown, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   AddGeometryColumn('public','Test',NULL,0,'MULTIPOLYGO...

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

So again any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, names edited. 

That would be the easy way, if the table was this small, but i need to find the selected (about) 200 polygons in table 1 and find all matching rows (matching on bloknr that is) in table 2, which has roughly 20.000.000 entries.

Comment: What have you tried actually? It is a very simple question (basics of SQL joins between tables that you can find in every SQL tutorial). Show us what have you tried and what fails.

Comment: I hope the update answers your doubt about my workflow - but it is true i'm a beginner to postgis and also somewhat to SQL although i'm getting the hang of it. The issue might be that cannot export the vector layer to qgis - because of the error described above.

Answer (score 0):

So i have come up with an answer, that will work in theory.

First make the desired geographical selection and make a new layer with the selection

- Then export the layer to the postgis database, with which you are connected
  Now it is possible to make queries in postgresql - and PGadmin.

Note that this does not keep the workflow in qgis - and for further processing of statistics etc. one will have to work on the integration between the new postgis layer and selection within this - and it doesn't quite solve the geographical/mapbased selection approach - although it will work